# How to disable event.preventDefault in React

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling, dom-events, mern

How can I disable `event.preventDefault()` in React after using it.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const {roomsleft, roomnumber, single, double, king, superking, bunk, sofa, button} = this.state
        axios({
            url: "/authentication/edit-rooms",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                roomsleft: roomsleft + 1,
                roomnumber : roomnumber,
                single : single,
                double: double,
                king : king,
                superking: superking,
                bunk: bunk,
                sofa: sofa,
                button: button,
            }
        })
        .then(roomsleft =>{
            if (roomsleft == roomnumber) {
                this.props.history.push('/accomodation-facilities')
            }

            else{
                //remove event here
                this.props.history.push('/edit-rooms')

            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

Comment: at what point do you want to disable it?

Comment: on the else statement

Comment: put a boolean flag which is set to false after preventdefault runs. and wrap the code inside else part to if(flag) {...else code here}

Comment: I can't do that because of the if and else statement is in .then I have to run the preventDefault so.then works.

Comment: What do you mean by wanting to disable event.preventDefault()? What is the current behavior and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you only want to disable preventdefault if else code runs. But you want to run preventdefault everytime it doesn't go inside else condition. Correct?

Comment: So event.preventDefault() stops from reloading i want to disable that and reload.

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 yes correct

Comment: so wrap prevent.default inside if(flag) { prevent.default }. Initially flag will be true. When else part runs, you set flag to false and if part runs set flag to true

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 The else part doesn't turn for that if statement but for the second one..

Comment: What do you mean? Please be more clear

Comment: You saying use an if at the start but then the ``` .then``` happens so a new if is create when i will use else the else is for the second and not the first if.

Comment: It's clear to me that you want to do something after your request is done. But once an even is cancelled, it's cancelled, you cannot undo that. There are ways to trigger the event again, but with your example it is really unclear what you're trying to do, so it's hard to help you.

Comment: All I am trying to do after the .then is triggered in the else statement I want the page to reload. But before that, the preventDefault event is true so I can't really reload the page now.

Comment: Try window.location.reload()

Comment: Already did and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

So the .then didn't get triggered at all so I did a few changes and I don't remember which but not in that part of code and then I tried window.location.reload() and now it works.